# In my code in while loop when the input number is negative I want to prompt the user again to enter the number, but I got error doing so

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Declare variable
        int inpNum;
        int total;

        // Prompt the user to input a number;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt user for positive nonzero integer.
        System.out.println("Enter a positive nonzero integer");

        // Convert the input into int.
        inpNum = keyboard.nextInt();

        // Assign value to total.
        total = 0;
```

Want to prompt the user if the input number is less than zero

```
    // Method to find sum of integers.
    while( inpNum < 0 )
    {
        System.out.println("Negative integer entered.\n"
                        + "Please enter a positive integer");
```

When I excetue the program, I got an error: cannot find symbol for

inpNum = keyboard.nextInt();

```
        inpNum = Keyboard.nextInt();
    }

        while( inpNum >= 1 )
        {
            total += inpNum;
            inpNum--;
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of the positive integers is " + total);

}
```

}

Comment: Does your code contain `keyboard` or `Keyboard`? Java is case sensitive.

Comment: There is a Java convention: variables and methods start with lower case, classes start with upper case, constants all upper cases.

Comment: @SmitPatel Buddy, try to follow naming conventions then you will not have these issues. Even others will also be able to work on it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
inpNum = Keyboard.nextInt(); //to
inpNum = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: welcome Smit. if its solving the issue, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the line `inpNum = Keyboard.nextInt();` you declared the scanner as`keyboard` and using it as `Keyboard` capitalized.